# How to get all output of bash -c commands in script?

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm writing a script that uses a lot of `bash -c` commands (more specifically lots of `bash -c oc delete pod podname -n namespace` commands) but I've noticed that these don't print their output to the terminal. How do I enable this?

Comment: A simple `bash -c "echo 'test'"` does print "test" to stdout, so there must be something else going on on your environmente which is supressing the output. Could you give us more information?

Comment: Are your aware that `bash -c oc delete pod podname -n namespace` only runs `oc` without any arguments?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `#!/bin/bash -v` the `-v` parameter is for verbose logging.

Comment: The `-v` option doesn't print commands' output (that should be automatic), it prints the text of the commands themselves before they're executed.